# LG G4 Interruptions: How do I prevent my phone from randomly going to "priority only?"

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, att, lg-g4

Priority only will go on randomly (probably a couple times a day). I don't have any "downtime" scheduled. Anyone else facing this issue? How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you tried factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this issue, never have seen it.  I wonder if it is an app or some other service causing it?  Which carrier do you have?  My only suggestion would be to install Tasker and set up a profile so that if your phone goes into priority mode, Tasker changes it back.  Of course this means if you want to manually change it you'll need to temporarily disable that profile.  It's not a very elegent solution, but it might work as a workaround...

Comment: It would be good if you mention how to create that profile and stuff in Tasker. I personally don't see anything as an answer here but as a comment. :) Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)